# get and use updated variables from a text file in a python function

Tags: python, variables, text

Here is my problem:

I have a text file (settings.txt) with some variables:

```
dataLogging=0
bootDelay=10
shutdownDelay=30
decimal1=5
...etc
```

I change the values of these variables from a web page. This is working fine.

I run a script (test.py) which imports and uses these variables:

```
import MySQLdb
from gps import *
import threading
from datetime import datetime
import sys
import os
import imp

f = open('/var/www/html/scripts/settings.txt')
global data
data = imp.load_source('data', '', f)
f.close()

global dataLogging, bootDelay, shutdownDelay, decimal1, ...

# variables
dataLogging = data.dataLogging
bootDelay = data.bootDelay
shutdownDelay = data.shutdownDelay
decimal1 = data.decimal1
...
```

Now, the rest of the script runs a class:

```
class GpsPoller(threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    global gpsd, lonvalue, latvalue, oldlon, oldlat, newlon, newlat, maxtrip

    gpsd=gps(mode=WATCH_ENABLE)

    self.current_value = None
    self.running = True
  def run(self):
    global gpsd, lonvalue, latvalue, oldlon, oldlat, newlon, newlat, maxtrip

    oldlon = ("%0.*f" % (int(decimal1), float(gpsd.fix.longitude)))  <---- here is my second problem
    oldlat = ("%0.*f" % (int(decimal1), float(gpsd.fix.latitude)))
  
  etc...
```

which is being called with ...

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

  if (int(float(dataLogging)) == 1):  <---- here is my first problem

    gpsp=GpsPoller()

    try:
      gpsp.start()

      while True:

        print "Loop running success"
        time.sleep(int(sleep))

    except(KeyboardInterrupt,SystemExit):
      # Close the database object
      db.close()
      gpsp.running = False
      gpsp.join()
```

The problem is that when I change the variables in the settings file via my web page, the changes are not being reflected in the test.py script until the script is stopped and then restarted.

For example, 'if (int(float(dataLogging)) == 1):' should start the script, but when the variable dataLogging is changed to '0', the script should stop. Basically, the variables should update after a predefined number of seconds.

Hope anyone can help!

Many thanks.

UPDATE:
This is what I have in the 'if(int(float(dataLogging)) == 1) block:

```
if(int(float(dataLogging)) == 1):

  # more variables
  lonvalue = "0.00"
  latvalue = "0.00"
  gpsd = None

  class GpsPoller(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        global gpsd, lonvalue, latvalue, oldlon, oldlat, newlon, newlat, maxtrip, dataLogging

        print "hello 1"

        gpsd=gps(mode=WATCH_ENABLE)

        self.current_value = None
        self.running = True
    def run(self):
        global gpsd, lonvalue, latvalue, oldlon, oldlat, newlon, newlat, maxtrip

        print "hello 2"

#########
#
# If I commment out everything from here to...
#
#########

        oldlon = ("%0.*f" % (int(decimal1), float(gpsd.fix.longitude)))
        oldlat = ("%0.*f" % (int(decimal1), float(gpsd.fix.latitude)))

        while gpsp.running:
          gpsd.next()

          # set new latitude/longitude to 4 decimal accuracy
          newlon = ("%0.*f" % (int(decimal2), float(gpsd.fix.longitude)))
          newlat = ("%0.*f" % (int(decimal2), float(gpsd.fix.latitude)))

          # compare old settings with new settings
          if ((oldlon != newlon) or (oldlat != newlat) or (dataLogging != 0)):

            # set old latitude/longitude to 4 decimal accuracy
            oldlon = ("%0.*f" % (int(decimal2), float(gpsd.fix.longitude)))
            oldlat = ("%0.*f" % (int(decimal2), float(gpsd.fix.latitude)))

            # set latitude/longitude to 7 decimal accuracy to enter into db
            lonvalue = ("%0.*f" % (int(decimal3), float(gpsd.fix.longitude)))
            latvalue = ("%0.*f" % (int(decimal3), float(gpsd.fix.latitude)))

            # datetime object containing current date and time
            now = datetime.now()
            dt = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

            try:
              if ((int(float(latvalue)) != 0) or (latvalue != nan) or (dataLogging != 0)):

                # Write data to GPSData.txt
                f = open("/var/www/html/scripts/GPSData.txt", "a+")
                f.write("%s" % maxtrip + "|" + lonvalue + "|" + latvalue + "|" + dt + "\n")
                f.flush()
                f.close()

                print "lonvalue: ",lonvalue,"latvalue: ",latvalue, " maxtrip: ",maxtrip," time: ",dt

                # Write to the database
                cursor.execute("INSERT INTO gps_data VALUES(null,%s,%s,%s,%s)", (maxtrip,latvalue,lonvalue,dt))

                # Commit the changes
                db.commit()

                # Snap-to-roads recommends an interval of 1-10 sec
                #time.sleep(int(sleepTime))
                time.sleep(10)

            # Unless there is a problem
            except:
              print "Loop running fail"

  gpsp=GpsPoller()

  try:
    gpsp.start()

    while True:
      print "Loop running success"
      time.sleep(5)

  except(KeyboardInterrupt,SystemExit):
    # Close the database object
    db.close()
    gpsp.running = False
    gpsp.join()

#########
#
# ...here, then the block stops executing if 'dataLogging = 0'
# and  restarts when 'dataLogging = 1'
#
#########

def testing():

  updateSettings()

  global dataLogging

  print "datalogging: ",dataLogging

  if (int(float(dataLogging)) == 1):

    gpsp=GpsPoller()

    try:
      gpsp.start()

      while True:

        print "Loop running success"
        time.sleep(int(sleep))
        testing()

    except(KeyboardInterrupt,SystemExit):
      # Close the database object
      db.close()
      gpsp.running = False
      gpsp.join()

testing()
```

Basically, I need the code within the commented out section to react to the change in the variable 'dataLogging'.

Many thanks

===================================

So, I've simplyfied the code. The object of the exercise is to take the 'dataLogging' value from the settings.txt file and, if the value is '1' get the lon/lat coordinates and if the value is '0' do nothing.

The code below correctly reacts to the change in the settings.txt file.
It prints 'dataLogging ON' if the value is '1' and changes to 'dataLogging OFF' if the value is changed to '0'. I can change the value at will and it always works.

The problem lies with the commented out code. If I uncomment the code, and the value is set to '1', then the logging of the coordinates does not stop even when the value is returned to '0'.

Sorry, my ignorance, but I am used to coding in php.

UPDATE 2:

```
# loop settings.txt file every 5 seconds and declare global variables
def updateSettings():

  f = open('/var/www/html/scripts/settings.txt')
  global data
  data = imp.load_source('data', '', f)
  f.close()

  # variables
  global dataLogging
  dataLogging =  data.dataLogging

  print "New datalogging from settings.txt ", dataLogging

  if dataLogging == 1:
    getGPSon()
  else:
    getGPSoff()

def getGPSon():
  print "dataLogging ON"

"""
  gpsd = gps(mode=WATCH_ENABLE|WATCH_NEWSTYLE)
  print 'latitude\tlongitude\ttime utc\t\t\taltitude\tepv\tept\tspeed\tclimb\tdataLogging' # '\t' = TAB to try and output the data in columns.

try:

  while True:

    report = gpsd.next()
    if report['class'] == 'TPV':
      print  getattr(report,'lat',0.0),"\t",
      print  getattr(report,'lon',0.0),"\t",
      print getattr(report,'time',''),"\t",
      print  getattr(report,'alt','nan'),"\t\t",
      print  getattr(report,'epv','nan'),"\t",
      print  getattr(report,'ept','nan'),"\t",
      print  getattr(report,'speed','nan'),"\t",
      print getattr(report,'climb','nan'),"\t",
      print dataLogging,"\t"

    time.sleep(2)
    #update()

    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit): #when you press ctrl+c
    print "Done.\nExiting."
"""
def getGPSoff():
    print "dataLogging OFF"

def update():
  while True:
    updateSettings()
    time.sleep(5)

update()
```

Comment: http://thepythoncorner.com/dev/how-to-create-a-watchdog-in-python-to-look-for-filesystem-changes/ check this article out. Might be helpful

Comment: Thank you Ritwik G. I got this almost working. The code now recognises when the setting.txt has changed and executes the code block that I added in 'def on_modified(event):'. However, this code block also has a 'if __name__ == '__main__':' in it, (see above) and I think that is causing the problem of an endless loop. Any ideas?

Comment: From a first glance it looks like that while loop serves no purpose. I think once you start the the thread with `gpsp.start()` you can add the `gpsp.join()`. If you take a look at the definition this function you can understand that it blocks further execution till the thread is completed. https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join.

Comment: Making small headway.... But, how do I start/stop a class from running based on a condition? i.e. 'if (int(float(dataLogging)) == 1)' starts the class GpsPoller, but when 'dataLogging' changes to '0' the class GpsPoller needs to stop. Sorry, very novice question!

Comment: Am not sure about that. It could depend on what exactly you do inside the run method of your class. To help with this can you add an update section at the end of the question with new code changes you made to recognize the settings file change?

Comment: Please see update!

Comment: You have used too many global variables and recursion to achieve what you needed. Both of which are bad. From the looks of it I feel like what you need is to pause the loop inside `run` method of `GpsPoller`. This is my suggestion. Write a function to read the file and return the `dataLogging` variable. Then use that function together with `while gpsp.running:` to control your while loop.

Comment: Please see UPDATE 2 !
Really hope someone can help with this problem. Surely must be quite simple??

Comment: I am assuming you probably doesn't require `getGPSoff`. This is what I suggest you to try. Remove `if dataLogging == 1:` and else conditions from `updateSettings`. In `getGPSon` inside while loop call `updateSettings()`. Then `if dataLogging != 1` add a sleep statement with `continue` in the else clause do the rest of your operation. Remove the update function just call `getGPSon` at the end of the code.

Comment: Check this link for the above changes and see if it makes sense https://gist.github.com/RitwikGopi/6deb59245dcec2d98d727e5fa03dbf3c